# Fragments - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have read many pages on here about this error with a fragment, but nothing helps so far. The error I am getting is:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: error inflating class fragment
```

I am making a Twitter client app, and using a fragment in my **ComposeTweetActivity.java**. So I have this class and a fragment class, then a layout to go with each. I will post all 4 of those files and my LogCat. If you need to see more, let me know. Thank you very much in advance.

**CompostTweetActivity.java**

```
package com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.R;
import com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.fragments.ComposeTweetFragment.OnComposeTweetListener;
import com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.models.Tweet;
/** 
 * Class hosts fragment for composing and posting tweets
 */
public class ComposeTweetActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnComposeTweetListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_compose_tweet); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.compose_tweet, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTweetCanceled() {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, i);
        finish(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onTweetPosted(Tweet postedTweet) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("new_tweet", postedTweet);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        finish(); 
    }

}
```

**ComposeTweetFragment.java**

```
package com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.fragments;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.R;
import com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.activities.MyTwitterApp;
import com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.helpers.AsyncTweetSave;
import com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.models.Tweet;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

/**
 * Class represents a screen to compose and post tweets. User is warned if text
 * typed passes the 140-character limit
 */
public class ComposeTweetFragment extends Fragment {

    private Activity  activity; 
    private Button    btnCancel,
                      btnTweet;
    private ImageView ivUserImage;
    private TextView  tvUserName;
    private EditText  etNewTweet;
    private boolean   alreadyToasted = false;

    private OnComposeTweetListener listener; 


    public interface OnComposeTweetListener {
        public void onTweetPosted(Tweet postedTweet);
        public void onTweetCanceled();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity); 

        if (activity instanceof OnComposeTweetListener) {
            listener = (OnComposeTweetListener) activity;
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement "
                                        + "OnTweetComposedListener interface");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compose_tweet, parent, false); 

        setupButtons(v);
        setupImageView(v);
        setupTextView(v);
        setupEditText(v);
        return v; 
    }

    private void setupButtons(View v) {
        btnCancel = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel); 
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onTweetCanceled(); 
            }
        });

        btnTweet = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnTweet);
        btnTweet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tweetBody = etNewTweet.getText().toString();
                tweet(tweetBody);
            }
        }); 
    }

    private void setupImageView(View v) {
        ivUserImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivUserImage);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(getActivity().getIntent()
                .getStringExtra("user_image_url"), ivUserImage); 
    }

    private void setupTextView(View v) {
        tvUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);
        tvUserName.setText("@" + getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("screen_name")); 
    }

    private void setupEditText(View v) {
        etNewTweet = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etNewTweet); 

        // Show soft keyboard when EditText field requests focus
        if (etNewTweet.requestFocus()) {
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.showSoftInput(etNewTweet, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT); 
        }

        etNewTweet.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!alreadyToasted && s.length() == 140) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "You've reached the 140-character"
                            + " limit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    alreadyToasted = true; 
                }
                else if (s.length() > 140) {
                    etNewTweet.setTextColor(Color.RED); 
                } else {
                    etNewTweet.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); 
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
        });

    }

    private void tweet(String tweetBody) {
        MyTwitterApp.getRestClient().postTweet(tweetBody, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, JSONObject jsonTweetResponse) {
                Tweet newTweet = Tweet.fromJson(jsonTweetResponse); 
                new AsyncTweetSave().execute(newTweet); // Might need to disable
                listener.onTweetPosted(newTweet);
            }   

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e, JSONObject error) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**activity_compose_tweet.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#185277"
    tools:context="com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.activities.ComposeTweetActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentComposeTweet"
        android:name="com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.fragments.ComposeTweetFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/fragment_compose_tweet" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_compose_tweet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#185277" >

  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
         android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cancel_button_outline"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/btn_cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTweet"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tweet_button_outline"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/btn_tweet" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
         android:background="#ffffff"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivUserImage"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" 
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_user_profile_dark" />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivUserImage"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:text="@string/twitter_handle" />

         </RelativeLayout>   

         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/etNewTweet"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="160dp"
             android:padding="10dp"
             android:background="#ffffff"
             android:gravity="top"
             android:hint="@string/et_new_tweet_hint"
             android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
             android:imeOptions="actionDone" /> 

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**LogCat**

```
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp/com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.activities.ComposeTweetActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.activities.ComposeTweetActivity.onCreate(ComposeTweetActivity.java:19)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     ... 11 more
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.fragments.ComposeTweetFragment.setupEditText(ComposeTweetFragment.java:113)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at com.codepath.apps.mytwitterapp.fragments.ComposeTweetFragment.onCreateView(ComposeTweetFragment.java:74)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
04-19 06:20:15.443: E/AndroidRuntime(8555):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
```

Comment: what is line no 113 in ComposeTweetFragment?

Comment: Hi, it is the InputMethodManager: 'if (etNewTweet.requestFocus()) {
   InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   mgr.showSoftInput(etNewTweet, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT); 
  }'

Comment: okey than follow raghunandan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

to

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

This

```
private Activity  activity;
```

is not initialized any where

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed the crash. I can now at least open the activity (although other errors, still but this one is fixed). I am curious though, why would it point to my XML when the error was in the Activity? Any idea?

Comment: As a beginner, I am always trying to understand the mysterious LogCat. :P